# Creating a branch from 2 branches that haven't yet been merged in GitHub

Tags: git

Given:

- I have 1 feature branch (feat1) and 1 main branch (main).
- All PRs are squashed and merged to the main.
- feat1 is going to be merged to main.
- Rebase is used to keep the branches up to date.

Scenario:
Code can be added to a new feature branch (feat2) and at the same time it can be kept up to date with feat1 using rebase. The problem will come when feat1 merges in to main. At that point feat2 will need to be rebased with main which will create rebase conflicts.

Question:

1. Is there a way to create the branch feat2 from un-merged feat1 and main, such that when the merge happens at some point, rebasing with main won't create conflicts? I am thinking that when the feat3 is created the feat1 "squash and merge commit" (the SHA of this commit will be the same as the SHA that will be generated when the actual merge happens) should be applied to main so as to prevent any conflicts as mentioned in the scenario.
2. Is there a way to keep the feat2 branch updated, with changes from both main and feat1, after it has been created as discussed in 1?

P.S: This question is not concerned about the public nature of the feature branches and how rebasing negatively affects other developers' work.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid conflicts with a little extra work when calling rebase. Say feat2 is 2 revisions:

```
git rebase --onto origin/main feat2~2 feat2
```

Then it doesn't matter that feat1 was squashed when merging. You can also use the old **unsquashed** tip of feat1 or its last revision below feat2 instead of `feat2~2`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's clear, but this answer assumes that OP takes the advice presented in the question: Either branch `feat2` off of `feat1`, or rebase `feat2` onto `feat1`. Then, after `feat1` is merged into `main`, do what this answer says to fix up `feat2` without conflicts.

Comment: Side note, best practice might dictate that `feat2` not have any dependency on `feat1`, whenever possible. Then a regular rebase would suffice after other branches are merged in.

Comment: I disagree with that last statement about dependency. You start working on top of `feat1` _probably_ because there is a dependency. What you need to be careful about is that when you move `feat2` around, make sure **not** to carry `feat1` revisions along as it is a separate effort (and that is what we do when we rebase the way I say in the answer).

Comment: Right. We're on the same page here. I think the question assumes `feat2` depends on `feat1`, and your answer handles what was asked. I was just pointing out, more of a comment to OP than to your answer, that maybe having a dependency between two in-progress feature branches should be generally avoided, if possible. (Perhaps that's more or a theoretical statement than a practical one; I see it happen all the time with good reasons.)

Comment: I see it often too, and I see where you are coming from. It's just a matter of _knowing what you are doing_ so that you don't mess up. If you are working on top of a feature branch (or even, working with little pieces of incomplete work from other branches... guilty as charged), make sure to clean up the mess before you publish it. The biggest thing to be careful about is that if you are on top of another branch, that other branch might move without you realizing it.... it could be as simple as a rebase... it could be as complex as a complete refactor that will break your branch.

Comment: That comment is not for you, @TTT, I know you are fine. Just a general guide for whoever comes reading this thread.

Comment: I wish everyone would "make sure to clean up the mess before you publish it". I don't know how many times I see a brand new mess on a protected branch, where the code is actually fine, but the list of commits is atrocious, and neither the developer nor any of the PR reviewers glanced at the list of commits before approving. It makes me want to force them to use squash merge sometimes. :)

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answers! I mostly like @eftshift0's answer as it works beautifully on small branches (low number of commits). Is there a way to get the "feat~2" without manually counting the commits (for branch with lots of commits)? merge-base is an option but squash and merge throws it off.



P.S.: I felt "list of commits is atrocious", Github has the option of enabling squash and merge only on a repo. We have that turned on and it has cleared up our history nicely. No more commits saying "review comments".